# Welcoming and Farewell Dinner for or Welcoming and Farewell Dinner of

Tags: word-usage

Which phrase is correct:

> Welcoming and Farewell Dinner **for** Residen

or

> Welcoming and Farewell Dinner **of** Residen

?

Comment: I think that you missed a "t". It should be "resident"

Answer (score 1):

"For" greatly implies that the dinner was not organized by Residen and was held to graciously welcome him and send him off.

"Of" just implies that the main celebrant or the main reason why the dinner was held is Residen. The one being welcomed and sent off is Residen.

Both are alright, but the usage and context of them are different. In an invitation, use the second one.